# How do i add a value to an email?

Tags: php, mysql

Lets say I have an email. Then I have an input with like 6, on database should be now 6, then I add another value like 11 and now it should be 17. I have like no ideia on how to do this.

The closest thing I did was sum the entire column but that only works for 1.

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','form');

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT sum(sumemail) FROM data");
    $lines = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    while($lines = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      echo "<br><br>Total de fotocópias:";
      echo $lines['sum(sumemail)'].'<br/>';
    }
?>
```

I wanted to use this code but i dont know how

```
UPDATE sumemail =  sumemail + $value
```

I expect to have like 10 emails, all with different values each.

Answer (score 1):

So you just need to know how to use the `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE <Table> SET sumemail =  sumemail + '$value'
```